# Mercurial: Prevent Untrusted warning from printing out

Tags: mercurial, hgrc

When performing some action on another user's repo, you will see the message

```
Not trusting file /home/bob/repo/.hg/hgrc from untrusted user bob, group users
```

This is fine, and I don't necessarily want to trust `bob`, but when running certain commands, I don't want to see this output as it can interfere.  It is printed to stderr, but I don't want to redirect all stderr output to null, nor do I want to redirect it to stdout and suppress it.

Is there any way to simply prevent mercurial from printing this?  `-q` does not do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can configure the warning:

```
[ui]
report_untrusted = False
```

The config settings are [documented online](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#ui) and in the built-in help (`hg help config`) and in the manual page (`man hgrc` on a Unix-like system).

Comment: Sort of... you can add `--config ui.report_untrusted=False` as needed to any command. You can also add the setting to a `.hg/hgrc` file to use it in a particular repository.